# Globe not displaying in my cesium application

Tags: javascript, 3d, cesium

The below code doesn't display the default Cesium globe. When I run my file, its just a black background. Why is it so?

```
<style>
@import url(../templates/bucket.css);
</style>
<div id="cesiumContainer" class="fullSize"></div>
<div id="loadingOverlay"><h1>Loading...</h1></div>
<div id="toolbar"></div>
<script id="cesium_sandcastle_script">
function startup(Cesium) {
 'use strict';
  var terrain = Cesium.createDefaultTerrainProviderViewModels();
  var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
   terrainProviderViewModels: terrain,
   selectedTerrainProviderViewModel: terrain[1],
   timeline: false,
   animation : false,
   vrButton : true,
   selectionIndicator : false
 });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default map provider in Cesium is Bing Maps. To keep the default you will need a key from Bing. Here is what you need to add one line above the Cesium.Viewer:

Cesium.BingMapsApi.defaultKey = 'YourPersonalKeyFromBing';

Another option would be to switch to a different map provider.
Hope this helps, Reuben